# Find path between x pairs of vertices in undirected graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am looking for the most efficient algorithm to find a path between every $x$ pair of nodes assuming $n$ total number of nodes in an undirected graph $G$ where $x$ is approx 1% of $n$. What are the possible algorithms and data structures I can use instead of just doing depth-first traversal from every node in $x$?

One thing to note is for my purpose, I have to find the path between random $x$ pair of nodes frequently (every epoch). So, I would tend to save more on time as compared to space.

Comment: Do you want any paths, or shortest paths? Do you want the paths to be edge or node disjoint?

Comment: Any path would work for my use case. And the paths should be edges (an ordered list of nodes in the path). I'm not sure what is node disjoint is in a path.

Comment: Then, you can just keep a spanning tree (if $G$ is connected, a spanning forest otherwise), and use for each pair the unique path for that pair in the tree. Would that be enough for your need?